# Select ComboBox in Windows Forms ToolStrip

Tags: .net, winforms, combobox, c++-cli, toolstrip

I have a problem focusing a ComboBox in a Windowsforms "ToolStrip" (C++ Cli).

I used the Designer to create a ToolStrip in my form and added a ComboBox (System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripComboBox) and it is visible and enabled.
When the form is loaded I want that Combobox to be selected, so I tried the following in the form-constructor.

```
this->CBox1->focus()
```

and

```
this->ToolStrip1->focus()  
this->CBox1->select()
```

none works.

Does anybody know how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ToolStripComboBox` class contains a `ComboBox` property that enables you to access its embedded `ComboBox` control. This appears to work (C# code):

```
this.Cbox1.ComboBox.Select();
```

Comment: Thanks alot. It works perfectly. I found some info about that ComboBox inside the ToolStripComboBox, but i couldn't make it work :(